# Discord navbar message div xpath [Selenium C#]

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Good evening! I have a lot of trouble finding the xpath for a particular element in discord.
Here is what a discord navbar looks like.
[image: Discord's navbar]
I wish to make a program with C# and selenium that clicks on the top left icon that says Kai.
With this I wouldn't have to manualy go to each persons chat using urls, but just clicking on their circle.
I believe I would have to do this with the `Actions` class, but I have a lot of trouble finding the xpath.
Here is what the html of the page looks like.

> (It is important to note that if no one has messaged you the div for this icon wouldn't exist) I think I can overcome this using the Wait.Until() function.

```
<nav class="wrapper-1_HaEi guilds-2JjMmN" aria-label="Servers sidebar">
  <ul role="tree" tabindex="0" data-list-id="guildsnav" data-jump-section="global" class="tree-3agP2X">
    <div class="unreadMentionsIndicatorTop-2bTgUU">
      <div class="scroller-3X7KbA none-1rXy4P scrollerBase-1Pkza4" dir="ltr" style="overflow: hidden scroll; padding-right: 0px;">
        <div class="tutorialContainer-1pL9QS"></div>
        <div style="opacity: 1; height: 56px; transform: scale(1);">
          <div class="listItem-3SmSlK">
            <div class="pill-22lZHo wrapper-z5ab_q" aria-hidden="true"></div>
            <div class="listItemWrapper-3d87LP">
              <div class="wrapper-2PSQCG">
                <svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48" class="svg-2ifYOU" overflow="visible">
                  <defs>
                    <path d="M48 24C48 37.2548 37.2548 48 24 48C10.7452 48 0 37.2548 0 24C0 10.7452 10.7452 0 24 0C37.2548 0 48 10.7452 48 24Z" id="d8070a58-e300-4574-b123-8f05218c284e-blob_mask"></path>
                    <rect id="d8070a58-e300-4574-b123-8f05218c284e-upper_badge_masks" x="28" y="-4" width="24" height="24" rx="12" ry="12" transform="translate(20 -20)"></rect>
                    <rect id="d8070a58-e300-4574-b123-8f05218c284e-lower_badge_masks" x="28" y="28" width="24" height="24" rx="12" ry="12" transform="translate(0 0)"></rect>
                  </defs>
                  <mask id="d8070a58-e300-4574-b123-8f05218c284e" fill="black" x="0" y="0" width="48" height="48">
                    <use href="#d8070a58-e300-4574-b123-8f05218c284e-blob_mask" fill="white"></use>
                    <use href="#d8070a58-e300-4574-b123-8f05218c284e-upper_badge_masks" fill="black"></use>
                    <use href="#d8070a58-e300-4574-b123-8f05218c284e-lower_badge_masks" fill="black"></use>
                  </mask>
                  <mask id="d8070a58-e300-4574-b123-8f05218c284e-stroke_mask">
                    <rect width="150%" height="150%" x="-25%" y="-25%" fill="white"></rect>
                    <use href="#d8070a58-e300-4574-b123-8f05218c284e-upper_badge_masks" fill="black"></use>
                    <use href="#d8070a58-e300-4574-b123-8f05218c284e-lower_badge_masks" fill="black"></use>
                  </mask>
                  <foreignObject mask="url(#d8070a58-e300-4574-b123-8f05218c284e)" x="0" y="0" width="48" height="48">
                    <div class="wrapper-3kah-n" role="listitem" data-list-item-id="guildsnav___1081284114512101459" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Kai Wellness Companion">
                      <img class="icon-3AqZ2e" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/907606359405633536/435ba02fd58a45d54fb0d66716c09cab.webp?size=48" alt=" " width="48" height="48" aria-hidden="true">
                    </div>
                  </foreignObject>
                </svg>
                <div class="lowerBadge-3j0ZAg" style="opacity: 1; transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
                  <div class="numberBadge-37OJ3S base-3IDx3L eyebrow-132Xza baseShapeRound-3epLEv" style="background-color: var(--status-danger); width: 16px; padding-right: 1px;">1</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The Xpath of the foreign object for the Kai icon is `/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/nav/ul/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/svg/foreignObject` But it doesn't work inside my program or when I try to do CTRL+F, it doesn't select it.
I would be really grateful if someone can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I watched this amazing guide on youtube - https://youtu.be/ku7vb4ox8M0
This is the XPath

```xml
//nav[@aria-label = \"Servers sidebar\"]//div[@class = \"listItemWrapper-3d87LP\"]//div[@class = \"wrapper-3kah-n\"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of Selenium developers asking for help with "the" XPath for identifying a particular element, and the use of the word "the" is a sign that they often have a particular misconception about XPath. Moving past this misconception is key to solving problems like this one.

NB experienced XPath developers will usually think in terms of "an" XPath expression for identifying a particular element, rather than "the" XPath, which reflects an understanding that there are *infinitely many* different XPath expressions which can be used to identify a particular element. The issue is how to choose a good XPath expression from among those infinite options.

Often when I see people talk about "the" XPath, it turns out the XPath in question is one which some tool (a browser inspector or similar) has given them for a particular element, and it'll be an expression that traverses every child element from the root element down to the target element, and it'll be full of positional predicates (e.g. `[1]`, or `[2]`, etc). These kinds of XPath expressions are easy for a browser to come up with, but they are *not*, in general, good XPath expressions to use in your code. Avoid!

In your case, you mention that your criterion for identifying the element is that it has a particular label, yet your XPath expression doesn't mention that label. Here's a simple XPath which *does* rely on the label.

```xml
//div[@aria-label="Kai Wellness Companion"]
```

What's better about this XPath?

- it's more concise
- its meaning is immediately obvious to a human
- it corresponds directly to the criterion a human would use to identify which button to click, and this makes it more robust (changes to other parts of the HTML are less likely to stop it working)