Tinder Xpath like button
i'm searching for the xpath for the like button of https://tinder.com/app/recs
it should be this
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div[4]/button/span/span/svg/g/path
and the code is:
like_button = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div[4]/button/span/span/svg/g/path"
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, like_button)))

but the console give me an empty array and the bot is not working. Someone can help?

You may need to specify an SVG namespace. That svg element (and its descendants) have their own XML namespace which is http://www.w3.org/2000/svg
But also, maybe you could come up with a more reliable / less fragile XPath? That one makes a lot of assumptions about the div structure of the page which are liable to change. Usually better to use an XPath which doesn't care where the button appears on the page, and instead identifies it by its id, or something similar.

see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677143/discord-navbar-message-div-xpath-selenium-c/75679031#75679031
